# Default Windows domain user profile settings and behavior

Tags: active-directory, user-profile, samba4

I'm about to use Samba to create a Windows domain, primarily to enforce security GPO (using RSAT) after a data theft incident by an ex-employee before she left.

What is the default behavior of the profiles once they are created by an user?

- Does it allow the user to log in with the same credential on a different PC in the domain? If so, how is the profile handled?
- If I explicitly allow roaming profiles, where will it be stored by default? Or am I to specify it manually? What are the best practices for handling such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it allow the user to log in with the same credential on adifferent PC in the domain?

Yes.

> If so, how is the profile handled?

Each profile is local to the computer that the user logs onto. There is no profile synchronization between computers. Changes to the profile on one computer are not reflected in the profile on any other computer.

> If I explicitly allow roaming profiles, where will it be stored by default? Or am I to specify it manually?

You need to manually create a network share for the roaming profiles.